# PHP submit error

Tags: php, html, forms

Hy guys, I'm learning PHP and I've downloaded XAMPP on my machine. I've problem with handling form. I created a form using HTML and stored it in htdocs in xampp folder as requested in tutorial. When I open form in HTML it works fine, but when I click Submit, it won't work. Here is an output when SUBMIT pressed:

```
$comments
We will reply to you at $email.

\n" ?>
```

And here is my PHP code for this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<title>Form feedback</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php #Script 2.2 - handle_form.php

    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];

    echo "<p>Thank you, <b>$name</b>,for the following comments:<br /><tt>$comments</tt></p>
    <p>We will reply to you at <i>$email</i>.</p>\n"

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP's not being parsed.

Comment: How should I fix this? I've put <?php at the beginning and ?> at the end. I haven't forgot this.

Answer (score 0):

Like Fred says, PHP's not being parse. Do your  `<?php` at the begining.

Comment: Yes, I have <?php at the beginning, as you can see. But, still doesn't work. I can't figure out what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your local server is running, because PHP's is not parsed.
After add `;` in the end of the `echo`, and check if your variables exist

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
} else{
  $name = '';
}
```

and for all other variables.